# Declaring variables in c#

Tags: c#

I have recently started studying programming and I would like to ask this question, what is better for my code performance or what is the correct way of doing this?

```cs
void FindBones()
{
    string boneName = GetBoneName();
    if (boneName == "Leg" || boneName == "Arm" || boneName == "Neck")
    {
        // do things
    }
}
```

Or like this

```cs
void FindBones()
{
    if (GetBoneName() == "Leg" || GetBoneName() == "Arm" || GetBoneName() == "Neck")
    {
        // do things
    }
}
```

Should I always declare my variable or not? Thank you.

Comment: Call it once. Why call a method more than once just to keep testing the (supposedly) same return value?

Comment: Assign it once, like the first snippet. Otherwise it will possibly call that function multiple times.

Comment: In the first example, you call `GetBoneName` once. In the second, you're calling it three separate times, which could potentially produce three different ocasions of function overhead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418045/does-call-method-slow-down-performance) for more info.

Comment: Why do people rush to close questions! It is valid enough. Are we so professional on this website that people can't ask simple questions? There is enough problems in the word with COVID-19 for us to not be helpful to anyone at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

The first approach is definitely what you would go with. Also it's recommended to use implicit types.

```
void FindBones()
{
    var boneName = GetBoneName();
    if (boneName == "Leg" || boneName == "Arm" || boneName == "Neck")
    {
        // do things
    }
}
```

Comment: My apology, yes, I meant the first approach is better. I've updated my answer. Using var simplifies your code. Your variables are still strongly typed. check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables) for more info about using implicit local variables

Comment: It's recommended to use implicit types [when the type of the variable is obvious from the right side of the assignment, or when the precise type is not important](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions#implicitly-typed-local-variables).

Answer (score 0):

First approach is preferred.

In this case it is a good practice to use a variable because function call usually adds a slight overhead. If function is computationally intensive then it effects performance drastically.

Also value of `GetBoneName()` do not change here. So both blocks of code works fine. But in case function value changes (Eg. : `Random.next()` ) the if block may not work as intended in second block.